# How do I obtain the last value generated in a primary key field using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This is a SQL Server 2005 T-SQL Question. I have a table that has an integer primary key, which is not an identity column.

How do I obtain the last value generated as a unique primary key value, regardless of whether that record has been subsequently deleted?

Imagine this table:

```
TABLE
COL_PK    VALUE1  VALUE2
1         FDSF    RWERWE
2         SDSS    £$£$£
3         FDFSD   ))FFFFFF
```

Moments later, I delete record 3.

However, I now want to work out the next new value for the COL_PK column. I can't do this by using this query:

```
SELECT MAX(COL_PK) + 1 FROM TABLE
```

..because this will calculate 3 - This is not the next PK value. How do I obtain 4 - The next new Pk value?

Comment: [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: @Tim "...which is not an identity column..."

Comment: It does, however, beg the question: **why** is it not an identity column? Solving this is why identity columns exist. Any check you do on the current values is a race condition. My advice - use `IDENTITY` and, as noted, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Answer (score 4):

You will need to either:

a)  Store the last generated number in another table, update on every insert and generate your key off this.

b)  Do not physically delete a record, but rather have some sort of deleted flag on it, keeping your number in the table.

c)  Just make it an identity key...

With (a), you will need to be careful of 'race' conditions, so you don't wind up with two attempted inserts for one key.

Comment: +1 : Not sure why you would do anything other than use an `IDENTITY` column *(option c)* and then call `SCOPE_IDENTTY()` to find the last inserted value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, if it's not an identity column... perhaps you shoud have logical deletes in stead of physical deletes, or have a separate table to give you the last assigned value (this is a common practice on some business like insurance companies and the like).